# How do I promt user x amount of times based on their input on the first question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a scheduler that gets user input by their **name**, **# of jobs** they have access in and what **kind of jobs** are those. My problem is that if **# of jobs** == 4, then, **kind of jobs** should prompt user 4 times but since they're both inside their own functions, **# of jobs** resets which makes **kind of jobs** only prompt once.

What I've tried, combine them together in a function  so that **# of jobs** won't reset and made a for loop but instead of prompting the user 4 times, it displays;

```
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: wash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
['Marc', 'WASH']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
['Marc', 'WASH', 'WASH']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
None
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected result would be;

```
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: SMT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: TEST
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

["SMT","TEST"]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
full_employee = []

def employee_name_input():

    while True:
        employee_name = str(input("Enter your first name: ")).strip().capitalize()

        if not employee_name.isalpha():
            print("Invalid input. Please try again!")
        else:
            full_employee.insert(0,employee_name)
            return access_jobs_input()



def access_jobs_input():

    access_num = int(input("How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): "))
    if access_num <= 4:
        access_jobs = str(input("Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: ")).strip().upper()

        for num in range(access_num):      
            full_employee.append(access_jobs)
            print(full_employee)

        if not access_jobs.isalpha():
            print("Your input is invalid. Please try again")
            return access_jobs_input()    

    else:
        print ("You are entering more than 4 access and it is not authorized. Please try again!")
        return access_jobs_input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues which I will outline below.

1. You are adding every job `access_num` number of times, but you need to add it only once.
2. Use a while loop instead of recursion to ensure the input is only done `access_num` number of times, and for invalid input.
3. Define `full_employee` inside your function, and actually call the function to make it work
4. Check for conditions greater than equal to 1 as well
5. Check if the input is valid by comparing it to list of valid jobs, instead of checking `isalphanum`
6. Your `employee_name_input` function should return a string
7. Your `isalpha` for name won't work if I have a space in the name, unless you only want first name without any spaces

The code below should work for you. Check out the comments to understand what is happening

```
def employee_name_input():

    employee_name = ''

    #Try till you get a valid name
    while True:
        employee_name = str(input("Enter your first name: ")).strip().capitalize()

        #Ask to retry if invalid name, else break the loop
        if not employee_name.isalpha():
            print("Invalid input. Please try again!")
        else:
            break

    #Return name of employee
    return employee_name

def access_jobs_input():

    #List to hold input of jobs
    full_employee = []

    #List of valid jobs
    valid_jobs = ['SMT', 'TEST', 'REWORK', 'BOX BUILD', 'SHIPPING', 'WASH']

    #Try until valid access number is provided
    while True:

        # Get number of jobs
        access_num = int(input("How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): "))

        #If access num is between 1 and 4
        if 1 <= access_num <= 4:
            idx = 0

            #While access_num jobs are provided
            while idx < access_num:

                access_jobs = str(input("Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: ")).strip().upper()

                #If entered job is invalid, don't increment the index and ask to try again
                if access_jobs not in valid_jobs:
                    print("Your input is invalid. Please try again")

                #If entered job is valid, append it to input of jobs and increment index
                else:
                    full_employee.append(access_jobs)
                    idx+=1

            return full_employee
        #Else return empty list
        else:
            print("You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!")


employee_name = employee_name_input()
access_jobs = access_jobs_input()
result = [employee_name]+access_jobs
print(result)
```

Possible outputs will be.

```
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): -1
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!

How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 5
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!

Enter your first name: decenttaro
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 2
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: SMT
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: WASH
['Decenttaro', 'SMT', 'WASH']

How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 3
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: XYZ
Your input is invalid. Please try again
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: ABC
Your input is invalid. Please try again
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: BOX BUILD
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: XYZ
Your input is invalid. Please try again
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: WASH
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: ABC
Your input is invalid. Please try again
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: REWORK
['BOX BUILD', 'WASH', 'REWORK']

Enter your first name: Decenttaro
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 5
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): -1
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 2
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: SMT
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: WASH
['Decenttaro', 'SMT', 'WASH']

Enter your first name: Decenttaro
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 5
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): -1
You are entering invalid number of access and it is not authorized. Please try again!
How many jobs do you have access in? (1-4): 2
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: SMT
Please, TYPE: SMT, TEST, REWORK, BOX BUILD, SHIPPING & WASH: WASH
['Decenttaro', 'SMT', 'WASH']
```

Comment: I have a function that ask for name before this function. How would I incorporate all of them so that the end result would be ["DecentTaro", "SMT","TEST"]?

Comment: In the access_num, if you put more than 4. It will print your name and warning but it won't go through the loop to ask it again.

Comment: Added it, please check!

Comment: I know I'm asking too much now and I really appreciate your help  but I need to since I'm a self-taught and no one would do code review for me. So what if in access_jobs, user type SMT, SMT and I don't want repeating of jobs. What would be the best solution for that?

Comment: You can look at using a set: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set